# Building Ember.js Fails

Tags: rake, ember.js

I pulled the latest source from github. 
I'm trying to build:

```
stephan@E6520:~/dev/ember.js$ rake
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- net/github-upload
```

the trace:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `load'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

github upload seemed to be missing so
I installed github-upload using the following:

```
rvm install github-upload --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

But i keep having the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same issue, try to execute "bundle install" and then "rake" again (hope I remember correctly)

Answer (score 1):

I removed github-upload requirement in the RakeFile.
Then I got other 'errors' i could solve again. By running the suggested bundle install
And now emberjs Builds.